# Migration from Standalone Solar to SolrCloud in AWS

Tags: solr

Our Developers is working in Local Standalone Solr Server and we have many cores in Local Solr. Now we are planning to migrate it to SolrCloud in AWS Infrastructure for replication purpose with numShards:3 and replicationFact:3. We don't need data to be migrated from Local Solr server to AWS SolrCloud. We only need to transfer Core from Local Solr to collection in SolrCloud. I am newbie in these can you please any help me in these.

1) In layman word we only need to transfer content in Conf folder of core to SolrCloud Collection and we don't need to transfer data(data folder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1) Create a new `collection` in SolrCloud with `config set` name same as of core.

2) Move the `conf` folder of the core in Local Standalone Solr Server to SolrCloud 'Collection' Folder.

3) Run zookeeper's zkCli.sh commands from bash to upload the `conf` file to all SolrCloud server.

```
cd /opt/solr/server/scripts/cloud-scripts/ 
bash zkcli.sh -cmd upconfig -confdir /opt/solr-7.4.0/server/solr/collectionname/conf/ -z IP1:2181,IP2:2181,IP3:2181 -confname confname
```

Reference : https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/using-zookeeper-to-manage-configuration-files.html#UsingZooKeepertoManageConfigurationFiles-UploadingConfigurationFilesusingbin_solrorSolrJ